# Assign 0 to variable in gcc extended assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int x=0, y=0,i=100;
    for (;i<1000; i++,x+=32){
        if (x == 25*32) {
            y+=32;
            asm volatile("pushl %%eax\n\t"
                         "movl $0, %%eax\n\t"
                         "popl %%eax\n\t"
                         :"=a"(x)
                         :"a"(0)
                         );
        }
        printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
    }
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is, set the variable x to 0 but I don't quite understand what the assembly code does, and it actually does set x to 0 but I'm not sure whats going on. can somebody explain what's going on? (just for the sake of learning assembly and C).

Comment: i think volatile means in this case execute in the loop / inline. the first bit pushes a value from eax to the stack, moves eax value to general register $0 then pops the stack to the register (think lifo) the 'original' value of eax, a is a register for 'x' and gets given the value of 0 (assignment). the assignment happens via the push/pop of the bit above. sorry bad explanation and my be wrong as new too. [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.4) is some reading

Comment: @Ti okay so, let me guess, the "$0" in the mov instruction stores a value of 0 into eax and then when I do "a"(0) the $0 gets moved to the output "x"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what your asm construct says:

- In `"=a"(x)`, you tell the compiler that the assembly will write (`=`) to the %eax (`a`) register, and you want the compiler to assign that result to x (`(x)`).
- In `"a"(0)`, you tell the compiler you want it to put a 0 (`(0)`) in %eax (`a`), and the assembly will read it.
- Then `push %%eax` saves %eax on the stack, `movl $0, %%eax` puts 0 in %eax, and `popl %%eax` restores the saved value to %eax.

So, what happens is:

- The compiler puts 0 in %eax.
- Your instructions save 0 on the stack, move 0 into %eax, and restore 0 from the stack.
- The compiler uses the 0 in %eax as the value of x.

So, this works, but it is inefficient. You can get the same effect with this:

```
asm volatile("movl $0, %[MyName]"
    : [MyName] "=r" (x)
);
```

What this says is:

- There are no inputs (because the second “:” is absent).
- As before, the `=` tells the compiler these instructions will write a result.
- The `r` says the result will be written to a register, but the compiler gets to pick the register.
- The `[MyName]` tells the compiler to change `%[MyName]`, where it appears in the assembly code, to the name of the register the compiler picks.
- As before, the `(x)` says to use the value in the register after the assembly code as the new value of x.
- Finally, the instruction `movl $0, %[MyName]` says to move 0 to the register named by %[MyName].

Because the compiler gets to pick the register, you do not have to save and restore it in the assembly language. The compiler is responsible for making sure it does not need that register for anything else.

Being able to name the operands as I have done with `[MyName]` is a new feature in GCC. If your version does not have it, you can do this instead:

```
asm volatile("movl $0, %0"
    : "=r" (x)
);
```

Without names, each operand gets a number, starting at 0, and incremented in the order the operands appear in the input/output specifiers. Since we had only one operand, it was %0.

Comment: By the way, movl gives a warning in GCC 4.7.1: "main.c:243: Warning: using `%ebx' instead of `%bx' due to `l' suffix" all I had to do is to remove the "l" and it compiled with no warnings.